# how to use another xml in same Activity in android

Tags: android

In my project i want to display some data 
        on ListView which is on another xml by the help of SimpleAdapter. It show
        right answer if the listview in xml of the activity which is refered in 
        setcontentview. i show you by code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   String Name="name";
   String Fathername = "fname";
   ListView lst;
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arylist ;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   arylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    lst =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst);
    HashMap<String,String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashmap.put(Name,"Aasim");
    hashmap.put(Fathername,"Pervaiz");
    arylist.add(hashmap);

    SimpleAdapter sadt = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, arylist, R.layout.rss_item_list_row, 
   new String[]{Name,Fathername}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.pub_date});
    lst.setAdapter(sadt);

   }
}
```

It show right answer because listview is present in xml setcontentview (link) how to display 
       on listview if xml is not linked in setcontentview.

Comment: If you don't set the view how will it display? Please be more clear what you want to achieve

Comment: i have one activity and two xml layouts. From one xml.Layout i take data and that layout is refered in setcontentview. if i display data on listview and is present in layoutone that is display data but when i want to display data on listview in second xml layout  then it show nullpointerexception on setAdapter () see last line of code in coding block.